# Geth and whisper default

Tags: go-ethereum, whisper

I was playing with `dumpconfig` and after that added `--shh` and dumped configuration again to see the differences but there weren't any.
My section of the Whisper config is:

```
[Shh]
MaxMessageSize = 1048576
MinimumAcceptedPOW = 2e-01
```

Does this mean I need to use `--shh` always while using `--config` option, e.g:

```
geth --shh --config yourfile.toml
```

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. `--shh` enables the Whisper protocol to be used on your Geth node. If Whisper is not enabled, none of the configs you've set for it will be active.